# Populating an object from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, oop, dataframe, genetic-algorithm

Currently trying to implement Genetic Algorithm. I have built a Python class Gene 
I am trying to load an object **Gene** from a dataframe **df**

```
class Gene:
def __init__(self,id,nb_trax,nb_days):
    self.id=id
    self.nb_trax=nb_trax
    self.nb_days=nb_days
```

and then create another object **Chrom**

```
class Chromosome(object):

def __init__(self):
    self.port = [Gene() for id in range(20)]
```

And a second class Chromosome with 20 Gene objects as its property
This is the dataframe

```
   ID               nb_obj              nb_days
 ECGYE                10259            62.965318
NLRTM                 8007            46.550562
```

I successfully loaded the Gene using

```
tester=df.apply(lambda row: Gene(row['Injection Port'],row['Avg Daily Injection'],random.randint(1,10)), axis=1)
```

But i cannot load **Chrom** class using

```
f=Chromosome(tester)
```

I get this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chrom.py", line 27, in <module>
    f=Chromosome(tester)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Any help please?

Comment: The error is because the `Chromosome`'s `init` function doesn't accept any argument. Besides, it's not clear what you're asking. You want to pass a list of already created `Gene`s to `Chromosome` to recreate them again? Can you update your question with more information about the desire output?

Answer (score 1):

The error is misleading because it says `__init__` takes 1 positional argument (which is the `self` from the object of the class `Chromosome`).

Secondly, what you are getting from the operation on `df` in `tester` is actually a `DataFrame` indexed as `df` with one column of `Gene` values.

To solve this you would have to change the code along these lines:

```
class Chromosome(object):

def __init__(self, df):
    self.port = [Gene() for id in range(20)]
    self.xxx = list(df)
```